# Can I upgrade an iPhone from iOS 4 to to iOS 5 now that iOS 6 has come out?

Tags: ios, upgrade

If I have an iPhone running iOS 4 that I want to run iOS 5, but don't want to lose Google Maps by upgrading to iOS 6, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still download the IPSW files that contain iOS from Apple - [here's a list of all of them](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=750). Just find the correct 5.1.1 file for your model.

The problem is installing that IPSW. The trick to make iTunes use a specific IPSW instead of downloading the latest from Apple is to hold option (shift on Windows) while clicking the Update or Restore buttons. There is a limit to how long Apple will allow installations of old versions (without using jailbreak-related hacks), so you'll want to try this ASAP.

Comment: Once you have a working restore set - be sure not to accept the upgrade offer and keep that file around. You should be able to restore the device at the same level going forward.

Comment: And, FWIW, the window seems to be closed.